# mulesoft - how to get a hashmap in message.getInvocationProperties in groovy component

Tags: mule, mule-component

how to get a hashmap in `message.getInvocationProperties`

Hi Guys,

I am trying to use this in groovy component on 3.7.3 runtime.

```
import java.util.*;
import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope;

HashMap sample = new HashMap<>();
sample.put("name", "abc");
message.setProperty("datastore", sample, PropertyScope.SESSION);
HashMap dataStoreMap = (HashMap)message.getInvocationProperty('datastore');
```

It gives me an exception of `Cannot cast object '' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.HashMap'` . Any idea of how to fix this?

However the api suggests `message.getInvocationProperty(name`) returns generic datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the same answer from here: https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/44598/how-to-get-a-hashmap-in-messagegetinvocationproper.html

Replace the scope from `PropertyScope.SESSION` with `PropertyScope.INVOCATION`, then you will get the HashMap.

If you want to keep the map in SESSION scope, then change the last script with: `message.getProperty('datastore', PropertyScope.SESSION)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the scope from PropertyScope.SESSION with PropertyScope.INVOCATION, then you will get the HashMap. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Change property scope from SESSION to INVOCATION message.setProperty("datastore",sample,PropertyScope.INVOCATION );